# DistanceTo() doesn't give me stable measurements

Tags: android, gps, distance, latitude-longitude

I am working on an android app that fetch user's Location and calculate the distance between him and another location.

The problem is that DistanceTo function give me different measurements each time I pressed the button although that I don't move the device.

Sometimes it gives me perfect measurement (give me 18 M) and sometimes it gives me too bad measurements(53 M) while the real distance 15 M !
Hint : I need very accurate measurements accuracy < 4M

this is the code of get the location

```
LM = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = LM.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    try {

        LM.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 100000, 1, this);

        if (LM != null) {
            Loc = LM.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            LM.removeUpdates(this);
            if (Loc != null) {
                   //set the location

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the code of claculate the distance is so easy 
    Location1.distanceTo(Location2);

Comment: GPS measurements are inherently imprecise.

Comment: Ohh
What about the hundred amount of applications that use GPS and it give us accurate results ?!

Comment: ... They average the position over time. Any simultaneous measurements can differ by ones or even tens of meters. There are many variables that affect GPS accuracy.

Comment: @DaveNewton No, they don't average over time. (This is unfortunaltly not possible, at least not on iphone because the GPS position does not update untill moving) It's done differently in that apps.

Comment: @AlexWien This isn't iPhone; I don't really see how that's relevant.

Comment: @Dave Newton, Does android deliver GPS locations while standing still? I doubt, so it is relevant, unless you tell me the contrary.

Comment: @AlexWien It will if you set time/distance to 0, IIRC, although I'm guessing that could drain the battery fairly quickly. My point was that answering with iPhone information isn't helpful for an Android question, and I stand by that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the answer, good to know that android is capabale to disable the standstill filter. But independently whether such "static movement" happens, the distance counting problem is  usually not fixed by averaging. Other filter methods are used.

Comment: @DaveNewton it will not drain the battery, The GPS chip is active, independently whether you set 0 or 30m. There is no half active GPS, as some asume.

Comment: @AlexWien That doesn't seem to be the case according to experimentation, but YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton To whose experimetation?  For which Apps? I develop Distance counting for professional GPS Tolling solutions, none algo I have ever seen uses averaging. I think you have not implemented a successful distance counting. So you simply don't know.

Comment: @AlexWien I was referring to the power consumption. Put it back in your pants and settle down.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem.
In my app, I get the current location from any provider and then compute distances from a set of LatLng. This is done in a timer loop of 10 seconds.

lat01, lng01, lat02 and lng02 are fixed and I have verified that they don't change.
However in each timer loop, I get different values.

```
                            grep "in for" mymap.log  | sort | uniq 
                                in for loop dist 18.917835 <lat01> <lng01> <lat02> <lng02>
                                in for loop dist 324.48648 <lat01> <lng01> <lat02> <lng02>
                                in for loop dist 325.92554 <lat01> <lng01> <lat02> <lng02>
```

The logic is like this:

```
                    if(testtimer==null)
                    {
                        testtimer = new Timer();
                        testtimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Location loc1 = new Location("test");
                                loc1.setLatitude(lat01);
                                loc1.setLatitude(lng01);

                                Location loc2 = new Location("test");
                                loc2.setLatitude(lat02);
                                loc2.setLatitude(lng02);

                                for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
                                {
                                    log_write("distance loc1 to loc2 "+loc1.distanceTo(loc2));
                                }

                            }
                        },1000,10000);
                    }
```

Update/Fix:
Stop using google's Location.distancebetween & location.distanceto functions. They don't work.

Instead use the direct formula to calculate the distance:

```
double distance_between(Location l1, Location l2)
{
    //float results[] = new float[1];
    /* Doesn't work. returns inconsistent results
    Location.distanceBetween(
            l1.getLatitude(),
            l1.getLongitude(),
            l2.getLatitude(),
            l2.getLongitude(),
            results);
            */
    double lat1=l1.getLatitude();
    double lon1=l1.getLongitude();
    double lat2=l2.getLatitude();
    double lon2=l2.getLongitude();
    double R = 6371; // km
    double dLat = (lat2-lat1)*Math.PI/180;
    double dLon = (lon2-lon1)*Math.PI/180;
    lat1 = lat1*Math.PI/180;
    lat2 = lat2*Math.PI/180;

    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double d = R * c * 1000;

    log_write("dist betn "+
            d + " " +
            l1.getLatitude()+ " " +
            l1.getLongitude() + " " +
            l2.getLatitude() + " " +
            l2.getLongitude()
            );

    return d;
}
```

Comment: could you explain me more about the Timer ?

Answer (score 0):

The distanceTo function works, but your app has no filter to detect the situation when you are not moving.
Some smartphones like iphones have built in to deliver a GPS position only when moving.
What you are see is, so called static movement.

(Nearly all GPS reciver can be optionally be configured to supress the delivery of differnet positions while not moving. But as an App developper you can not change that fixed configuration.)

You have to write such a filter, to avoid different measures at the same position.

Comment: what do you mean by filter ?!

Comment: a filter keeps good and removes bad or irrelevant (Locations),

Comment: How to implement this filter ?!

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know "gps is lying" about the exact position about a "feew" meters. comercial apps that need more precision have a gps receiver at a known exact position and transmit the diference to the "lying gps" on a seperate channel so the gps position on the mobile can be corrected accordingly.

Comment: could you please explain more the this more " a gps receiver at a known exact position and transmit the diference to the "lying gps" on a seperate channel "  ?

Comment: No, there is no DGPS in commercial android apps. (Despite Waas and EGNOS) which is already enabled on his phone. His app is not intelligent enough to do an appropriate filtering.